# Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException using FileProvider

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-fileprovider

I'm getting this exception when trying to use FileProvider:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find configured root for content://com.abc/Android/data/com.abc/files/345345345.pdf   Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

I guess my file_paths.xml configures the FileProvider with the wrong path. My code:

file_paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path path="." name="." />
    <files-path path="com.abc/Android/data/com.abc/files/" name="files" />
</paths>
```

androidManifest.xml

```
<application android:label="@string/AppName" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.abc" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

What values should I put in `path` and `name` in `file_paths.xml`, to expose the file with the content URI: `content://com.abc/Android/data/com.abc/files/345345345.pdf`?

my code which creates the URI:

```
File newFile = new File (Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, filename);
                Android.Net.Uri androidContentUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile (Application.Context, Application.Context.PackageName, newFile);
                System.Uri systemContentUri = SystemUri (androidContentUri);
                return systemContentUri;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entry:

```
<files-path path="com.abc/Android/data/com.abc/files/" name="files" />
```

Should become:

```
<files-path path="files" name="files" />
```

**Path** in this case represents the files in the `files/` subdirectory of your app's internal storage area.

This application private subdirectory is the same as the value returned:

```
Application.Context.FilesDir;
```

So the file location within your app is:

```
var path = Path.Combine(Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, "files");
```

Comment: Thanks! I changed the `<files-path` to what you suggested, and also attempted to get my path in code (the bottom line of your answer) into my code. The result of the AbsolutePath already had "files" in it so I didn't use Path.Combine. But I'm now getting this error: `Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/com.abc/files/2534534.pdf`. Here is my code to create the file: `File newFile = new File (Application.Context.FilesDir.AbsolutePath, filename);`